# Specify a coverage goal for EvoSuite

Tags: evosuite

I would like to know whether I can specify a specific coverage goal (e.g., certain lines of a java file to be covered) before invoking EvoSuite. If it is possible, how should I put as command line? My goal is to obtain as many test cases as possible with my specified portion of code being covered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately is not currently possible. You might want to create a "feature request" at:

https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite/issues